# How to add sites in content query webpart?

Tags: content-query-web-part

We have programs and product environment, we want add both sites and subsites to the main page using content query web part? is it possible if yes how?

Answer (score 0):

please check this post it might helpful to you..

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/When-to-use-the-Content-Query-Web-Part-or-the-Content-Search-Web-Part-in-SharePoint-346a0f48-38de-409b-8a58-3bdca1768929

Answer (score 0):

If you have configured Search service application in your farm and associated with web application- publishing site collection- then its easier to use `Content Search Web Part` and fetch all the sub sites from the site collection and display it in a CSWP.

please refer  [this-link-sharegate](https://en.share-gate.com/blog/roll-up-sharepoint-2013-sites-using-search)

also refer [sharesilver.wordpress](https://sharesilver.wordpress.com/2013/10/24/content-search-web-part-for-specific-sharepoint-listlibrary/)